# C# Winforms animation

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, gdi+

I am trying to create an animation with C# windows Form, and I found out a very good library of Pavel Torgashov called Animator for WinForms:
[link of Animator for WinForms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548769/Animator-for-WinForms)

I have started using it and played around it for awhile.

The problem is that if I'm trying to use a control like label, and wanted to animate it in full screen bigger than 1366x768, it started flickering and the speed of the animation is slowing.

Has anyone else encountered the same issue? If so, how can I solve it?

Comment: WinForms is **not** well-suited to animating Controls like that: it’s just a thin wrapper over Win32’s built-in widgets which Microsoft wants people to forget. If you need an engaging UI for .NET then use WPF.

Comment: Well then, I guess I have  to start this project all over again!

Comment: The author of that library is VERY good in graphics theory, but the WinForms implementation is missing important handling of objects creation, especially when it comes to the generation of Graphics objects and disposing of the disposable objects created. The library leaks **heavily**: the memory usage can grow up to 1 GB **in seconds** with an Image of, say, `1600x1050`, and won't stop. It's not *production level* and it's built on .Net Framework 2.0. It can be reworked, though, to correctly dispose of everything each time a Frame is generated. After that, you can have full-screen animations.

Comment: That being said, depending on what kind of animations you want to produce, you may want to use existing, well tested, libraries that use DirectX rendering. Or, as noted, use a GUI framework as WPF that implements this kind of graphics out of the box and has built-in tools to generate (and control) animations. -- I.e., pick the right tools for what you want to build (not clear what that is, you didn't mention it).

Comment: I knew I was choosing the wrong  technology for this project, but I was thinking it would be simple to just stick with Winforms since I was in a rush. But no luck, at the end of the day, I realized that it was my bad!

Answer (score 0):

The library you mentioned uses and manipulates screenshots. Nice trick but definitely not to be recommended in production code.

However, WinForms can do really smooth animations.

In 2009 [Richard Shepherd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141066/richard-shepherd) wrote some awesome code using interpolation methods. I forked a mirror on GitHub some years ago, added some more animations and made it available for newer .NET versions.

It's here: [FluentTransitions for WinForms](https://github.com/awaescher/FluentTransitions).

[image]